# CSS: Image preview - Circle-to-Rectangle on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

This is an admittedly simple question that may have been asked here already asked but I'm struggling here.

What I want is an image that has a circle preview that expands to a rectangle on hover (it also scales).  What I have is pretty close but the center kind of "bobbles" and I'm not a fan of the empty div approach...

```css
.card{
   color: #ff2772;
   border-radius: 15px;
   margin: 3px 1px;
   background-color: #2d3034;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 300px;
   min-height: 400px;
   display: inline-block;
   transition: .25s;
   cursor:pointer;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid #ff2772;
}

.button {
   background-color: #ff2772;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 30px;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

#seasonOne .test {
   background: url('http://placehold.it/250x200') 50% 50% no-repeat; 
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   transition: .3s;
   transform: scale(.9);
}

#seasonOne:hover .test {
   transform: scale(1);
   width: 250px;
   height: 200px;
   border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="seasonOne" class="card seasonOne">
   <h3>Season 1 (2009) - The Pilot</h3>
   <div class="test">
   </div>
   <p class="animated smallText fadeInRight">Ut cursus purus in lacinia tincidunt. Quisque lorem odio, posuere ut aliquam vel, fringilla at enim. Duis ligula lacus, viverra et sapien rhoncus, commodo euismod ipsum.</p>
   <a href="#area" class="button">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Like I said, what I have is pretty close.  It's just not centered properly which is driving me crazy. I also don't like having to set the image in the CSS rather than the HTML (though that's a minor gripe) Any ideas about a better way to go about this?

Edit: Okay to clarify:

1.) The scale from .9 to 1 is intentional

2.) The rectangular proportions (250x200px) are important. It's not supposed to be a perfect square.

3.) When I say the say the center 'bobbles" I mean it deviates. It's subtle but it shifts around a few pixels.  Sadly I don't think the problem is showing up in my snippet which means it's coming from somewhere else in my CSS :/ Here's it on my site (sorry for the cutesy art) [image: What the problems looks like]

I guess a better question is how can I achieve this effect without an empty div and guaranteed centered?

Edit 2:
The problem is in Firefox. You can see the art "vibrate" in this Codepen
http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/zrZwEQ

Comment: what do you mean the center bubbles?....to me it looks centered plus you have margin: auto;..please clarify

Comment: @Mark keyframes aren't necessary when the animation is a straight move from one value to another as in the post, transition will do. Keyframes are useful if you want the animation to move in stages, for example: if you wanted 80% of the effect to take place in 1s then in the next 1s to finish that effect while adding in another

Comment: answer edited accordingly since you have provided a codepen :D..see last snippet

Comment: @repzero Thank you for coming back to it! Another user pointed out that the stuttering was due to the changing width, which is a shame because I really liked the full width effect... Oh well, best answer to you!

Comment: @StephanieQ I removed my answer, it didn't solve the problem in the gif, thanks for clarifying - I haven't had the time to really examine this, however, I'd suggest removing every bit one by one apart from the image with it's animations and a bit of css to place it and see at what point it works nicely, this will help reduce the problem

Comment: @StephanieQ also, you may want to look at reflows and repaints, which are the different ways the browser changes the look based on a user action, such as hovering an image - I have a hunch you're expecting the browser to do rather a lot (animating the size of an image amongst other things) so you might be able to improve it by reducing the complexity of the hover state armed with knowledge of what the browser is doing under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason why you are getting the bobbling event**

You have set a transition property on hover which includes scaling the element to a bigger size. Hence, the background image is scaled as the div is scaled. Also what you are doing is setting an increase width which is irrelevant since transformation scale is also doing the same thing

change

```
#seasonOne:hover .test {
   transform: scale(1);
   width: 250px;
   height: 200px;
   border-radius: 0;
}
```

to

```
#seasonOne:hover .test {
        border-radius: 0;
}
```

Here is a snippet

```css
.card{
 color: #ff2772;
 border-radius: 15px;
 margin: 3px 1px;
 background-color: #2d3034;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 300px;
 min-height: 400px;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: .25s;
 cursor:pointer;
  text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid #ff2772;
}

.button {
background-color: #ff2772;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#seasonOne .test {
background: url('http://placehold.it/250x200') 50% 50% no-repeat; /* 50% 50% centers image in div */
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 100%;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
transition-property:border;
transition: .3s;
transform: scale(.9);
}

#seasonOne:hover .test {
   border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="seasonOne" class="card seasonOne">
 <h3>Season 1 (2009) - The Pilot</h3>
 <div class="test">
 </div>
 <p class="animated smallText fadeInRight">Ut cursus purus in lacinia tincidunt. Quisque lorem odio, posuere ut aliquam vel, fringilla at enim. Duis ligula lacus, viverra et sapien rhoncus, commodo euismod ipsum.</p>
<a href="#area" class="button">Read More</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT: looking at the codepen here is a snippet**

```css
.season img {
 float: left;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 animation-delay:0.1s; 
}

.season p.oneP {
animation-delay:0.5s; 
}
  
.season p.twoP {
animation-delay:0.75s; 
}
.season p.threeP {
animation-delay:1s; 
}
.season h2 {
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
background-color: #eee;
padding: 3px;
margin-top: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.season .smallText {
 animation-delay:0.2s; 
 overflow: hidden;
}
.season h6, .season .arts, .season h3 {
 text-align: center !important;
 animation-delay: 1.8s;
}
.next, .prev {
float: right;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 49%;
 animation-delay: 3s;
 border: 3px solid #EEE;
 border-radius: 15px;
}
.prev {
 float: left;
}
 .prev img.preview, .next img.preview {
  float: left;
 }
.previews {
 display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card{
 color: #ff2772;
 border-radius: 15px;
 margin: 3px 1px;
 background-color: #2d3034;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 300px;
 min-height: 400px;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: .25s;
 cursor:pointer;
   border: 1px solid #ff2772;
   text-align: center;
}
.floatRight {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 
}
#page-content .card h6 {
 padding: 10px 2px;
 background: none;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 transition: .3s;
 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


#page-content .card .smallText {
transition: .3s;
 background: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#page-content .card:hover .smallText, #page-content .card:hover h6{
 background-color: #ff2772;
 color: #2d3034;
}
.card:hover{
 background: #fff;
}

/*
.card img {
 width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
  transform: scale(.9);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 
}
/*.card .test {
 transform: scale(.9);
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;

}
*/




#seasonOne .test {
 padding:0;
  background-color: #fff;
 background: #fff url('http://i296.photobucket.com/albums/mm174/StuffieStephie/S1ChibiPreview2_zpsswyamase.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
         -moz-transition: 0.5s;
         transition: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
     -ms-transform: scale(.9);
     -moz-transform: scale(.9);
         transform: scale(.9);
 font-size: 0;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
         transform-origin: 50% 50%;

}

#seasonOne:hover .test {
 border-radius: 0;
}



hr {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
img.preview {
 transform: scale(.9);
 width: 200px;
 display: inline;
 float: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
.art img.preview:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.art img.preview:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.25s;
}

.logo{
 clear:left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
img.preview:hover {
 transform: scale(1);
 box-shadow: 0 15px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 0;
}
.season img.no-float {
  float: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .season h6 {
  clear: both;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
 .prev img.preview, .next img.preview {
  float: left;
 }

 .season p {
  clear: both;
 }
   .prev p, .next p {
  clear: none;
 }
 .season img{
  float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
 .card {
  width: 49%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.prev, .next{
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
 margin: 5px auto;
}
 .prev img.preview, .next img.preview {
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
 .card{
 width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />



<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css">

<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Sniglet:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kamicon.net/assets/styles/mainStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 


<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<div id="site-canvas">

<div id="page-content">
<section><h1>Help Me!</h1>
<p>The art shakes horribly when you hover over it in Firefox Why!?</p>
<div id="area" class="holder"></div>
<div class="previews">
<div id="seasonOne" class="card seasonOne">
 <h6 class="center">Season 1 (2009) - The Pilot</h6>
 <div class="test"></div>
 <p class="animated smallText fadeInRight oneP">Ut cursus purus in lacinia tincidunt. Quisque lorem odio, posuere ut aliquam vel, fringilla at enim. Duis ligula lacus, viverra et sapien rhoncus, commodo euismod ipsum.</p>
<a href="#area" class="button">Read More</a>
</div>


</div>
<hr/>

</section>
</div> <!-- #page-content -->


</div><!-- #site-canvas -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```